# How to display data from API on web page

Tags: html-lists

I have an API URL http://api.openchargemap.io/v2/poi/?output=json&countrycode=NL&maxresults=10
and I want to display this data in a web page in a list format, but I have no idea where to start. Can I use JS? Can anyone help?

Comment: Learning HTML would be a better start. Then use JS to populate a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use js but jquery is better and angularjs is the best, i made you an example in jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:"get",
    url:"http://api.openchargemap.io/v2/poi/?output=json&countrycode=NL&maxresults=10",
    success: function(data){
    result="";
    for(i in data){
    result+="ID: "+data[i].ID+" // UUID: "+data[i].UUID+"<br>";
    }
    $("#list").html(result);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can use Javascript but you need or localhost or some hosting for AJAX . You must use GET to get that information on your webpage . After AJAX you can use innerHTML function or console.log to see your result in console .

Comment: Thank you , I understand